# Bigcommerce Stencil Start Error

Tags: bigcommerce

I recently installed stencil on my local machine, and went through the stencil init process. However when I run stencil start I am getting the following error:

```
    { [Error: ../../node_modules/@bigcommerce/citadel/dist/tools/toolkit.scss doesn't exist!]
```

formatted: 'Error: ../../node_modules/@bigcommerce/citadel/dist/tools/toolkit.scss doesn\'t exist!\n        on line 13 of stdin\n>> @import "../../node_modules/@bigcommerce/citadel/dist/tools/toolkit"; // 1\n   --------^\n',
  message: '../../node_modules/@bigcommerce/citadel/dist/tools/toolkit.scss doesn\'t exist!',
  column: 9,
  line: 13,
  file: 'stdin',
  status: 1 }
{ [Error: ../../node_modules/@bigcommerce/citadel/dist/tools/toolkit.scss doesn't exist!]
  formatted: 'Error: ../../node_modules/@bigcommerce/citadel/dist/tools/toolkit.scss doesn\'t exist!\n        on line 13 of stdin\n>> @import "../../node_modules/@bigcommerce/citadel/dist/tools/toolkit"; // 1\n   --------^\n',
  message: '../../node_modules/@bigcommerce/citadel/dist/tools/toolkit.scss doesn\'t exist!',
  column: 9,
  line: 13,
  file: 'stdin',
  status: 1 }

I know this question was asked previously last year, but going with the provided answer and doing a fresh stencil install isn't working for me. There seems to be a problem with bigcommerce's cli as many of the css files it is trying to import are not being found. Has anyone worked through this problem and found a solution?

Comment: recreate your stencil theme bundle and upload it again

Answer (score 1):

First off I would delete your stencil configuration and re-run:

```
stencil init
```

If that doesn't work try to move to the root folder that holds your stencil files and run:

```
npm install
```

What this will do is install any npm packages that may not have been installed. It could be why the Stencil CLI can't find them.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to reinstall Latest version of Nodejs?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).